# Why are some panels just sketches?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I have been reading some Boku no Hero Academia and in some chapters (only very few) there have been panels, which looked like sketches and not like the rest of the manga. Since it were only single panels, I didn't think much of it. But while reading chapter 182, there have been whole pages like that (s. picture below).

Did the artists run out of time and so, they weren't able to complete all pages? Or is there a different reason for this?

> [image: picture])

Comment: I don't know about this particular case, but it's not unheard of for manga to be released in serialized form without some steps of the process being finished, usually because there was not enough time to finish. In such cases, the issue would usually be corrected in the *tankōbon* version.

Comment: @LoganM Really? That was the first time I saw/noticed it.

Comment: I first noticed this in Ao no Exorcist a few years ago. Since the I've seen several cases. If I remember well Bakuman manga&anime contained a part where they talked about how manuscripts sometimes get released in magazines as authors just can't finish them on time. At other times [mistakes are made](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2015/02/25/kodansha-apologizes-for-publishing-unfinished-pages-of-all-out-manga).

Comment: @Gorzius The posted link doesn't work.

Comment: @Geshode Was very common with HxH. You can find plenty of full chapters for it

Comment: Related (or dupe) in other series: [Why do some page contain a rough sketch?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/39159)

Comment: @Geshode Link works for me, tried it in 2 different browsers. It's an article from Crunchyroll. But here's the original Japanese article then: http://ebook.itmedia.co.jp/ebook/articles/1502/24/news149.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the explanations in the comments.

As expected, the "unfinished" look is most likely caused by a lack of time on the side of the artists.

I am surprised to hear, that it seems common enough.